# How does view process data with HTML form?

Tags: django

I am looking at this example.
This is search_form.html

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="/search/" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="q">
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
 </form>
</body>
<html>
```

Urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
# ...
url(r'^search-form/$', views.search_form),
url(r'^search/$', views.search),
# ...
]
```

And views

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from books.models import Book


def search(request):
 if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:
  q = request.GET['q']
   books = Book.objects.filter(title__icontains=q)
   return render(request, 'search_results.html',{'books':books,'query':q})
 else:
  return HttpResponse('Please submit a search term.')
```

When GET data is passed into the query string,

```
/search/?q=paris
```

what really happens?

The form in HTML is bound or unbound at this point?
I am newbie to Django, it would be nice if someone can explain.

Comment: If you hit submit, you simply make a new request, but now with another URL (in fact you can bypass the form, by simply writing the URL with the query parameters). Django parses the `?q=paris` in a `QueryDict` (an "advanced" dictionary that maps `'q'` to `'paris'`), and then the view will generate a new response.

Comment: Thanks,nice and simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form is an element in the browser, so Django does not know anything about the form at all. In the `<form>` tag it is specified what to do in case somebody clicks on the submit button (or the form is submitted in another way, for example by a JavaScript call).

When the form "fires" it depends on the `method` what will be done. Here the `method` is GET, so that means that the content of the form is wrapped in the URI (the `?q=paris` part). The webbrowser will normally make a new HTTP GET request, but now with the new URI.

Django will listen to the request, and it sees the querystring (the `?q=paris` part) and will turn it into a `QueryDict`. A `QueryDict` is some sort of dictionary (except that a key can contain *multiple* values), this will then be the `request.GET` part. Django will look at the other parts of the URI to determine to which view the request should be "routed" (that is specified in the `urls.py` file).

Then the view thus will query the `request.GET` to obtain the string that matches with the `'q'` key (here `'paris'`) and perform the proper logic.  In this case it will make a database query and look for `Book`s with `'paris'` as a substring in the title. It will then render a HTTP response (probably the template will render the results of the query, so a list of books where for every book, some details are displayed).

The browser thus obtains the response, and then will render this on the screen of the user, so HTML in the response is then translated to a visual page. It can result in extra queries (for example if the page contains `<img>` tags, the the corresponding images are fetched).

The `method` of a `<form>` can also be a POST (and some browsers even support other methods). In that case a HTTP POST request is made, and then the data in the form is encoded in the headers of the HTTP request (so it is *not* visible in the URI, which can be useful if it for example contains sensitive information). In that case the view can query `request.POST`, which is a `QueryDict` as well, to obtain the parameters.

Regardless of the specifics of the form, the idea is that the browser makes a request, and unless the information of the "old" webpage is stored in some form element or in the header, Django has no means to "see" what the state of the page was. In fact it is not necessary to make the request at a certain page. You could for example have requested `your.site.com/?q=paris` immediately.